# Windows Ce 5.0 vs Windows Mobile 6

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, accumulator

I'm thinking of purchasing **Opticon PHL 7112** accumulator which runs on Windows CE 5.0 i was wondering will i be able to:

1. develop an application that connects to an open MSSQL database
2. is there a capability to get data from a SOAP web service?
3. i saw that only visual studio 2008 support development for windows ce, is there a way to enable this on visual studio 2010-2012 ?
4. if possible to connect to MSSQL database how to do it
5. if only possible to connect to a SOAP web services how to do it

I'm new to windows CE programming. Also the development environment is Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a lot of experience in developer with WINCE.

It 'very easy to connect to a data source of type SOAP / WebServices and you can do it through VISUAL STUDIO, add ServiceReferences doing and following the instructions. 
Through SAOPA / WebServices Return the data you read from your database, you can also use local versions of Database (would not recommend)

You have to use to develop WINCE exclusively VISUAL STUDIO 2008 other versions no longer support this platform.

I have a lot of work on these types of devices, and for the maintenance and development use only one pc WIN7 + VS2008.

It 'a stable and effective technology.

Comment: thanks, i think i will buy this device and try to develop on it i will ask here if i have any problems.

Comment: Ok, if you have other questions I will be happy to help